# Exception calling "ExtractToFile" when unzipping

Tags: powershell, zip

I've tried a couple of solutions to unzip a file containing the path:

```
\Content\F_C\Jenkinsworkspace\workspace\BUILD.PROJECT.GENERICS\PROJECT_Generics\PROJECT.Generics\PROJECT.Generic\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp
```

but I get the error:

> Exception calling "ExtractToFile" with "3" argument(s): "Could not find a part of the path

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath F:\Jenkinsworkspace\workspace\BUILD.GENERIC.GENERICS\GENERIC.Generic.zip -DestinationPath F:\Jenkinsworkspace\workspace\BUILD.GENERIC.GENERICS\UNZIPED2 -Force
```

```
Exception calling "ExtractToFile" with "3" argument(s): "Could not find a part of
the path 'F:\Jenkinsworkspace\workspace\BUILD.GENERIC.GENERICS\UNZIPED2\Content\
F_C\Jenkinsworkspace\workspace\BUILD.GENERIC.GENERICS\GENERIC_Generics
\GENERIC.Generics\GENERIC.Generic\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\modules\
_protected\EPiServer.GoogleAnalytics\EPiServer.GoogleAnalytics.zip'."  
At
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:1033 char:25  
+ ...               [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile( ...  
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotFoundException
```

I'm guessing it's because I have a zip within a zip.

Comment: You're well under 255 characters from a glance, it does not appear the path is too long from the information provided.  Please provide a valid code snippet and an explanation of what you're doing so that someone can attempt to replicate.  Also, it helps to be as specific as possible.  PowerShell can run on many platforms (including Linux).  Due to the `\\` folder separator, I assume this is being run on Windows.

Comment: Note, before posting my question, I researched the maximum character limit for Windows Zip files as well as created a zip file containing a text file at the described path.  `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Content\F_C\Jenkinsworkspace\workspace\BUILD.PROJECT.GENERICS\PROJECT_Generics\PROJECT.GEnerics\PROJECT.Generic\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\test.txt`.  Creating a baseline test which replicates the offending zip file helps narrow down the cause of failure.

Comment: updated , thanks for the help !

Comment: If you read your error messages, Windows is unable to find part of your path.

Comment: @alex Now updated code snippet **does** show you are over 255 characters.  It seems to have some nested directories.  For example, `Jenkinsworkspace\workspace\BUILD.GENERIC.GENERICS` shows twice in your path which is strange.  Anyway, does `F:\Jenkinsworkspace\workspace\BUILD.GENERIC.GENERICS\UNZIPED2` exist on your computer?  The message says it does not exist.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem using the paths mentioned.  The problem does not occur when I shorten the paths.  I think your original guess of paths being too long is correct.

Comment: You should try to get Project.Generic into your folder structure more...

Comment: It's an application output . Can't find a way to change it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soved using this Blog :

https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/

changing the group policy solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

In our case, though the path was short, we were getting the same error.
Sharing our solution which might be useful for someone.

We were trying to unzip the package on our application server through powershell script. Basically powershell script runs on our build server & remotely connect to our application server. It was then trying to unzip the package present on application server.
The above scenario was working fine for quite some time before it starts to throw the error during unzipping.

**Solution:**
We found the reason was anti virus policy, which was blocking the unzipping through remote powershell script.

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of time, thank you for adding it